Create partitionless FAT32 filesystem on USB flash drive
I am diagnosing an issue with some USB sticks on an embedded Linux device that happens when a USB stick with a partitionless FAT32 filesystem is connected. I want to reliably recreate this situation.
How can I create a FAT32 filesystem directly on a USB flash drive?
If my flash drive shows up as /dev/sdc, mkfs.exfat /dev/sdc does work, but it creates an exFAT filesystem instead. mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc would create a FAT32 filesystem, but it complains that attribute "partition" not found". Adding the -I switch does not fix that. mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc1 works (when a partition table is created first), but that's not what I want.
I'll also accept a Windows-specific solution if it's possible to do this with Windows 10.

Kubuntu 23.10, mkfs.fat 4.2 here. sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda has just worked for me.

Does this helps? https://ezup.dev/blog/fat32-partitionless-voidlinux-liveusb.html

I've found that Win7 will format a (small) SD card that has a zeroed-out first sector (i.e. no MBR) with a FAT32 filesystem for the whole drive. There's no MBR or partition table just like a floppy. Suggest you try similar with a USB flash drive, or an SD card with a USB adapter. Windows will insist on formatting the drive on insertion/detection.

The output of mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc is:
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
attribute "partition" not found

That's it. This is clearly an error message.
It works anyways.

To whoever downvoted this answer: It's not my fault that the output of mkfs.fat doesn't make any goddamn sense. The USB stick is formatted correctly despite the error message, so mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdc is the answer to "How can I create a FAT32 filesystem directly on a USB flash drive?".
